# Using Apani VPN with Mac Yosemite

Tags: localhost, cgi

I upgraded to Yosemite but ever since I am unable to use Apani VPN client. The application works by accessing local host URL and port 1916. Localhost access works fine but when I add the port, I get an error that the page is unloadable. 
The complete URL for Apani is

```
http://localhost:9161/eac.cgi
```

Any idea of what I should do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions - you might try http://apple.stackexchange.com. Having said that, I had to use the Apani VPN on Mac OS X for a number of years and the support was shockingly bad - every time a new version of OS X came out their VPN broke and it took them months to fix it - I was so relieved when I finally got to switch to a different VPN.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I agree it's pain in the neck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a terminal shell:

```
su -
cd /Library/StartupItems/Nleac

./Nleac start
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to be super user. Be sure to do the "su -" first.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clearer (as I almost gave up), enter:

1. su (username) cd/Library/StartupItems/Nleac
   then
   Password :xxxx
2. sudo (your username) /Nleac start.
3. Password: xxxxxx enter